# Deep copy - An element of a void** - Member of struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memcpy, deep-copy

Below is the code,

```
/****** list.h **********/
#include<stddef.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

/***************** Usage-start ************/
typedef enum{false, true}bool;
typedef enum {CREATE_NEW_LIST, DOUBLE_THE_LIST, HALF_THE_LIST}Op;

#if defined(ARRAY)

  /* To ensure Encapsulation(i.e., maintain invariants of array) */
  typedef struct List List;

#elif defined(LINKED_LIST)

  /* To ensure Encapsulation(i.e., maintain invariants of linked list) */
  /* User will not get access to node*/
  typedef struct List List;


#else
  #error "Wrong list implementation macro name !!!"
#endif


void insertItem(List *, void *newItem);
void *deleteItem(List *, int listIndex);
List* createList(List *, Op opType);
```

---

```
/************* arrayImpl.c ***********/


#include"list.h"


/************ Representation - start ************/
typedef struct List{
  void **array;

  /* Following members for Housekeeping - Array enhancement*/
  int lastItemPosition;
  int size;
}List;

#define INITIAL_LIST_SIZE 50
List *createList(List *list, Op opType){
  if(opType == CREATE_NEW_LIST){
    list = malloc(sizeof(List));
    list->array = malloc(INITIAL_LIST_SIZE*sizeof(void*));


    /* Is it safe to initialise zero to  array of  pointers? */
    list->array = memset(list->array, 0, INITIAL_LIST_SIZE*sizeof(void *));

    list->lastItemPosition = -1;
    list->size = INITIAL_LIST_SIZE;
  }else if(opType == DOUBLE_THE_LIST){

    list->array = realloc(list->array, 2*(list->size)*sizeof(void *));

    list->lastItemPosition = list->lastItemPosition;;
    list->size = 2*(list->size);
  }else if(opType == HALF_THE_LIST){

    list->array = realloc(list->array, ((list->size)/2)*sizeof(void *));

    list->lastItemPosition = list->lastItemPosition;
    list->size = (list->size)/2;
  }

  return list;

}
```

---

```
/********** arrayImpl.c*********/
void *deleteItem(List *arrayList, int listIndex){
  void *returnElement; //Deep copy before freeing the object
  free(arrayList->array[listIndex]);

  /* Delete operation - O(n) operation */
  for(int accumulator = listIndex; accumulator <= arrayList->lastItemPosition; accumulator++){
    arrayList->array[accumulator] = arrayList->array[++accumulator];
  }
  arrayList->lastItemPosition--;


  /* House keeping - Half the list */
  if(arrayList->size > INITIAL_LIST_SIZE){ /* Minimum size maintained */
    if((arrayList->lastItemPosition + 1) == ((arrayList->size)/2)){
      arrayList = createList(arrayList, HALF_THE_LIST);
    }
  }
  return returnElement;

}
```

---

```
/***************arrayImpl.c***************/
void insertItem(List *arrayList, void *newItem){

  /* House keeping - Enhance the array */
  if(arrayList->lastItemPosition + 1 == arrayList->size){
    arrayList = createList(arrayList, DOUBLE_THE_LIST);
  }


  /* Insert new element - O(1) operation */
  arrayList->array[++(arrayList->lastItemPosition)] = newItem;


  return;
}
```

---

User code,

```
#include"list.h"

int main(void){

  List *arrayList = createList((List *)NULL, CREATE_NEW_LIST);


  if (arrayList == (List *)0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create list \n");
    exit(1); //Nothing else to do without arrayList
  }

  // Objects should only be on heap
  int *object1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *object1 = 777;
  insertItem(arrayList, object1);

  int *object2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *object2 = 888;
  insertItem(arrayList, object2);

  object1 = deleteItem(arrayList, 0);
}
```

---

I want to re-use `List` abstraction for writing `Stack` abstraction, as shown below with `push()`/`pop()`

```
#include"../list/list.h"
typedef struct Stack{
  List *stack;
}Stack;
```

Question:

In `deleteItem()` function, how to deep copy `arrayList->array[listIndex]` and return `returnElement` from `deleteItem()` function?

`pop()` would be calling `deleteItem()`

*Note: Compilation `>gcc -DARRAY main.c arrayImpl.c`*

Comment: All that code, and still no definition for `struct List`...

Comment: @twalberg Updated. All the code in `arrayImpl.c` come under  `#if defined(ARRAY).. #endif`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insertItem` didn't allocate an item - so `deleteItem` shouldn't `free` it.

```
void *deleteItem(List *arrayList, int listIndex){
  void *returnElement = arrayList->array[listIndex];

  /* Delete operation - O(n) operation */
  ....

  /* House keeping - Half the list */
  ....

  return returnElement;
}
```

Comment: Plus one, Idea is, If user provides allocated the data to store, then `insertItem()` has no choice but store. `insertItem()` has no idea what data user wants to create, so it receives data from user. But if user want to delete the item, user would just say what to delete, so `deleteItem()`. how to delete it? `deleteItem()` should take care

Comment: @overexchange User says delete from the list. If it means delete it the way you see it, then it makes no sense to return it: the `free()`d pointer is unusable.

Comment: I will re-use `deleteItem()` for `pop()`. When I write `Stack` abstraction

Comment: Looks like, what you said is correct? `arrayList->array[accumulator] = arrayList->array[++accumulator];` is taking care of deletion. Should not actually `free`, because the user needs it. I think I have to change `linkedImpl.c` accordingly.

Comment: One supplementary, Can I avoid multiple declarations in `list.h`? `typedef struct List List`